# History API in Safari - pushState / replaceState - state undefined

Tags: javascript, html, safari, pushstate

The following works in Chrome and Firefox, but not in Safari (6.0.2):

```
var data = [];
data.Message = "hi!"
history.pushState({Data:data}, '', document.location.href);
console.log(history);
alert(history.state.Data.Message);
```

In Safari, the console log for the history state is undefined, as is the message. The same is true for replaceState.

Fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/wYV9d/3/

Answer (score 2):

It's because I created Data as an array instead of an Object.

```
var data = {};
```

works just fine.